# Payment Authorization & Capture the Payment (Future) using PayPal-node-SDK (PayPal Express Checkout)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, paypal

I'm working with PayPal Express Checkout and and what i need to do is Authorize and Capture the payment later separately, my current PayPal flow is,

1) I create a payment using following code:

```
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

function createPayPal(req, res, itemsArray, redirectsTos) {
    var payment = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {},
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": sails.config.currency,
                "total": itemsArray.totalArrayAmount,
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": itemsArray.totalArrayAmount,
                    "fee": sails.config.PayPalCreateFee
                }
            },
            "invoice_number": req.session.invNum,
            "item_list": {
                "items": itemsArray.itemsArray
            }
        }]
    };
    sails.log.info('payment obj :', JSON.stringify(payment))
    payment.payer.payment_method = sails.config.PayPalPaymentMethod;
    payment.redirect_urls = {
        "return_url": res.locals.return_url_buy,
        "cancel_url": res.locals.cancel_url_buy
    };

    paypal.payment.create(payment, function(error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            sails.log.error(error);
            redirectsTos(({
                message: 'failure',
                redirect: '/paypal/error'
            }), null);
        } else {
        sails.log.info('Payment ID = ', payment.id);
        sails.log.info('User ID = ', req.session.userSession);
        var redirectUrl;
        for (var i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            var link = payment.links[i];
            if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
                redirectUrl = link.href;
                sails.log.info('goto:', redirectUrl)
                redirectsTos(null, ({
                    message: 'success',
                    redirect: redirectUrl
                }));
            }
        }
        }
    });
}
```

and Paypal returns me the order information and the redirect `urls` and i redirected the user to the `href` in `links` object. then when the payflow returns to me website it sends me

```
{
    paymentId: 'PAY-5FB60654T5508144abcxyzZLQ',
    token: 'EC-26U68825EW2123428',
    PayerID: 'QSABTRW6AHYH6'
}
```

and then i executed the payment using following code.

```
function executePayPal(req, paymentId, payerId, executedPayPal) {
    sails.log.info('in executedPayPal');
    var details = {
        "payer_id": payerId
    };
    var payment = paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, details, function(error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            sails.log.error('error in payment id in executePayPal function of paypal controller', error);
            var err = JSON.stringify(error);
            var errParsed = JSON.parse(err);
            crashHandlingService.appCrash(errParsed, 101202);
            executedPayPal(({
                message: 'failure',
                redirect: '/paypal/error/'
            }), null);
        } else {
            executedPayPal(({
                message: 'success',
                redirect: '/paypal/success/'
            }), null);
        }
    });
}
```

Now what this code basically do is

1. Create the payment,
2. Redirect the user to paypal page C
3. Capture the payment.

and what i actually want to achieve is

1. authorize the payment ->
2. capturing the payment so that i can capture the payment some later time in some cronJob or service.

   And redirect the user to paypal page in the middle of above flow, i really don't know how to authorize, redirect and then capture payment.

So please guide me in this regards.

Note: i've read the following paypal documentation but not able to understand. and please keep in mind that i need to show payment detail on paypal page and also the coupon code and its discount on the payment page.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/#authorize-the-payment
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: i think i've found the solution, by usign following link i can do it but not sure, im goning to test it.   https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/af279e3087e60c13ca65c5baf3faba5fab70ce48/samples/payment/execute.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution and i thought i should post it here so that it could be helpful for other.

So there are basically 4 following steps and one have to you use [PayPal Node SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK)

- Create Payment.
- Redirect User to PayPal.
- Execute Authorized Payment.
- Capture Authorized Payment.

To Create Payment you can use payment.create method of PayPal Node sdk [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/execute.js#L34).

.Create Method will return url links in `"href"` to redirect user to PayPal page so redirect the user to PayPal page.

After returning from pay PayPal page you have to run .execute method of PayPal Node SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/execute.js#L61), using `payer_id` and `paymentId` recived from PayPal.

and finally when you need to capture the amount of the authorized transaction you had to `.authorization.capture` method of PayPal Node SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/authorization/capture.js#L14), by providing amount and the 17 digits authorization id recived in execute authorize response.

Code & Response sample are provided below in case if the links doesn't works in future.

`.create Code`

```
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://return.url",
        "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        for (var index = 0; index < payment.links.length; index++) {
        //Redirect user to this endpoint for redirect url
            if (payment.links[index].rel === 'approval_url') {
                console.log(payment.links[index].href);
            }
        }
        console.log(payment);
    }
});
```

`Response Sample`

```
{
  "id": "PAY-17S8410768582940NKEE66EQ",
  "create_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:02Z",
  "update_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:04Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "authorize",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "type": "visa",
          "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx0331",
          "expire_month": "11",
          "expire_year": "2018",
          "first_name": "Betsy",
          "last_name": "Buyer",
          "billing_address": {
            "line1": "111 First Street",
            "city": "Saratoga",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95070",
            "country_code": "US"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "tax": "0.03",
          "shipping": "0.03"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "4RR959492F879224U",
            "create_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:02Z",
            "update_time": "2013-01-31T04:12:04Z",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "total": "7.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "parent_payment": "PAY-17S8410768582940NKEE66EQ",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/4RR959492F879224U",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/4RR959492F879224U/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-17S8410768582940NKEE66EQ",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-17S8410768582940NKEE66EQ",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

`.execute Code`

```
var paymentId = 'PAYMENT id created in previous step';

paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Get Payment Response");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
    }
});
```

`Response Sample`

```
{
  "id": "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
  "create_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:26Z",
  "update_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:28Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "aurthorize",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "bbuyer@example.com",
      "first_name": "Betsy",
      "last_name": "Buyer",
      "payer_id": "CR87QHB7JTRSC"
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "tax": "0.04",
          "shipping": "0.06"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "1KE4800207592173L",
            "create_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:26Z",
            "update_time": "2013-01-30T23:44:28Z",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "7.47"
            },
            "transaction_fee": {
              "value": "0.50",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "parent_payment": "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1KE4800207592173L",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/1KE4800207592173L/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

`.authorization.capture Code`

```
var capture_details = {
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "4.54"
    },
    "is_final_capture": true
};

paypal.authorization.capture("5RA45624N3531924N", capture_details, function (error, capture) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(capture);
    }
});
```

`Response Sample`

```
{
  "id": "6BA17599X0950293U",
  "create_time": "2013-05-06T22:32:24Z",
  "update_time": "2013-05-06T22:32:25Z",
  "amount": {
    "total": "4.54",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "is_final_capture": true,
  "state": "completed",
  "parent_payment": "PAY-44664305570317015KGEC5DI",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/capture/6BA17599X0950293U",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/capture/6BA17599X0950293U/refund",
      "rel": "refund",
      "method": "POST"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/5RA45624N3531924N",
      "rel": "authorization",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-44664305570317015KGEC5DI",
      "rel": "parent_payment",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get more information from [REST API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) And [PayPal-node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/).

Forgive me if the response sample are somehow a little bit change because i've copied it from PayPal web.

Thanks.