# Getting the user email after payment to send code to email

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Im creating a system in node.js where a user pays for a product and after payment they get sent a receipt with a special code in it which they can then redeem.

How do i get the user's email and the paymentID (which they paid with) after they have been redirected to the success page after payment.

Im using the "paypal-rest-sdk" and i have everything else working.

[Payment Authorization & Capture the Payment (Future) using PayPal-node-SDK (PayPal Express Checkout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076221/payment-authorization-capture-the-payment-future-using-paypal-node-sdk-payp) -- If you read the top answer on that post, im basically asking how to get the information of the paymentId from the user who just paid in my GET request of the successfulpaymenturl so i can run the .execute code and see the person who paid's email and then i can send them the unique code they get after buying the product.(http://prntscr.com/ds0fpo)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please add some code showing what you've tried doing and how it has failed.

Comment: I havent really got any code working as i dont know how to do it and googling for a long time hasnt helped a lot, all i want to know is if there is a way after paying and the user being sent back to the return_url for me to get there email and payment.id, possibly from the request sent back or if there is a smart way of doing it with variables/cookies or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Ah silly me, when you get redirected to your success page you get 3 params in req.query with one of them giving me the payment id and allowing me to check if it was approved andthen allowing me to run the execute code in the link above so i could get the payer info and in there was the email!